# Op-amp with BJT circuit problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt, negative-feedback, emitter-follower

I'm studying for EE final exam

First Question: what is the current through the red LED?
I have been working on this problem. So far, what i got is that with 5V come in the non inverting input of the op amp so that the inverting should be at 5V, also. From that point, i can found the emitter current which equal to (5V-0V)/160.

Second question: What is the purpose of the BJT?
I am not sure what is the purpose of the BJT on this problem? is it acting like a switch or a buffer?
[image]

Comment: It’s a common emitter current amplifier with current sensing on the Re which matches Vin, so I=Vin/Re

Comment: I think that in BJT: iC=iB+iE. So the current do through the RED LED is not the same as the emitter current I believe

Comment: This circuit is constant current regulator, it regulates the emitter curent to 31.25mA no matter what Vcc is.   Ic (led current) is 31.25mA - Ib , so Ic is almost the same as emitter current.

Comment: The BJT is in linear mode (not saturated) where negative feedback like if R2 voltage =5.1V  decreases base current to maintain emitter current constant 31.25mA i.e. holds R2 voltage at 5V.

Comment: There is no need of R1; just remove it (and see what will change). Also, do another experiment - disconnect the op-amp inverting input from the BJT emitter and connect it directly to the op-amp output. Compare the two configurations and make a conclusion which of them is better and why.

Comment: Q1 acts as a variable resistor controlled by current sensing feedback error in the circuit. But with 12V for a 2 or 3 V LED it is overkill as a simple single R is adequate to limit current based on simple KVL and the voltage difference

Answer (score 1):

A typical opamp can’t supply more than 25mA (obviously this change from manufacturer)

That’s the purpose of the bjt: supply the extra current

Answer (score 1):

The BJT is technically working as a booster, it amplifies in power (or current, to be exact), in this case.

The opamp senses the current thru the emitter resistor. It then drives the base so that the current is equal to the 'programmed' value (on the non-inv input). Thanks to retroaction this works independently of Vbe, hFE or whatever other condition.

However all the excess voltage (from the 12V supply) has to go somewhere, in this case it's dissipated by the BJT (and in part in the emitter resistor, about 150mW). Since power dissipation of opamps is usually quite limited unless special parts are used the BJT cover the gap.

By the way it would work with a MOSFET too, if you can reach a sufficient gate level (a logic level part would be probably needed here).

Answer (score 1):

**1. The LED current is *approximately*: 5V/160ohm = 31.25mA**

R2, the op-amp and the NPN form a closed loop with negative feedback on the emitter current. **The op-amp tracks the 5V on its (+) input and drives the NPN base until the (-) input is also 5V.** With loop closure we know the **R2 resistor IR drop will be 5V**. The LED, NPN emitter and resistor are in series, so we know R2 (NPN emitter) current and thus the *approximate* LED (NPN collector) current.

Now above I used those weasel-words *approximately* and *approximate*. Why? We know the LED current (that is, \$I_C\$) will slightly less than the emitter's (\$I_E\$) because the base current (\$I_B\$) adds to the total emitter current (\$I_E = I_C + I_B\$).

To find the **actual LED current** we need to know the **transistor current gain (Beta, \$\beta\$)** to calculate \$Ic\$ and thus the LED bias point. Be aware that your instructor may be asking you to figure that out.

With some algebra we can compute \$I_C\$, as follows.

First, the BJT current gain:

- \$I_C = I_B*\beta\$

Based on the fact that we know R2's bias point, find \$I_E\$:

- \$ I_E = 5V / R2 = 5V / 160 \Omega = 31.25mA\$

Then find \$I_B\$:

- \$ I_E = I_B + I_C = I_B + I_B*\beta = I_B(1 + \beta)\$
- \$ I_B = \frac {I_E} {1 + \beta}\$

And finally, find \$I_C\$:

- \$ I_C = I_E - I_B = 31.25mA - \frac {31.25mA} {1 + \beta}\$

If we use 100 for \$\beta\$, this comes out to **about 30.94mA** for the LED current. Note that because \$\beta\$ will vary widely, this cannot be counted on as an exact value. (Exercise for the student: how would you fix that?)

Simulation bears this out ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAXEFFGkPKphT8qVCExrQaKMJQyQZxMCjzFCSGITx1s2LPmI1imCGDggAJgwBmAQwCuAGw5swhYUKjcMw7B8s2Ds5MjgwW4F6isOwA7t6%20Hj4ghHyQbHqCSRJ48V4QomwASrnZJQKRtGLColDQCGwATrlgNHyeaDlihGkA5rkd-byRbLYiY25U5cTgSCxIZvDmkqSk2ITYlDQINNoISPOLaU0TYzx85YJoaXGeas0qUGw3Sco5ni2pT-c55a%20PcVNCOMHmliuUUrQchCajQqBpInU2EA)):

[image]

**2. The NPN is a current buffer.**

The NPN and op-amp form a control loop to set the LED current. The NPN boosts the current capability higher than what the op-amp itself can provide.

With appropriate circuit adjustments, the NPN can increase the voltage range as well.

Answer (score 0):

The op amp BJT and feedback loop operate like a voltage controlled current sink. The BJT will change its current based on the current coming from the op amp which is based on the voltage between the terminals of the op amp. The op-amp will try to adjust output to make the positive and negative terminals equal.